# What Thread are my Events being Fired On?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, backgroundworker

I'm trying to verify that my events are being fired on the correct thread.  I know that the functions linked to the events occur on the same thread that they are fired from, but I'm a bit confused if they are actually being fired on the correct thread.

I have a `Form` with a `BackgroundWorker` and a custom class object called `Uploader` on this `Form`.  This `Uploader` object is constructed in the constructor of my extended `Form` class such as this:

```
public partial class UploadProgress : Form
{
    private BackgroundWorker uploadWorker;
    private Uploader uploader;

    public UploadProgress(S3Info info, List<System.IO.DirectoryInfo> directoryList = null )
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.uploadWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        //Configuration of BackgroundWorker & EventHandlers removed for simplicity of example

        uploader = (directoryList != null) ? new Uploader(info, directoryList) : new Uploader(info);
    }
```

The `Uploader` object can fire two different events depending on the upload progress.  In the `form_load()` event method I am passing the `Uploader` object into the `BackgroundWorker` as a parameter via the `RunWorkerAsync(object)` method.

Now my question is this:  Since the the `Uploader` object's long running methods are firing events in the  `BackgroundWorker`'s DoWork method are those events occuring on the BackgroundWorker's thread or are they happening on the UI thread since that's where the object was constructed and the events were setup?

Comment: There's no magic here, those events run on the BGW's thread.  You can use the BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged event to get code to run on the UI thread.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks.  I just needed someone to confirm my thoughts since I was a bit confused.  Trying to get more into multithreading and asynchronous programming and just want to make sure I understand everything properly.

Comment: @GrantWinney nope, they never touch the UI.